# My conda environment use default "six" package, not what I installed in conda environment

Tags: python-2.7, conda, python-packaging

```
(python2.7) (23:28:22) ~$ python
Python 2.7.14 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Dec  7 2017, 17:05:42)
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import six
>>> six.__version__
'1.5.2'
>>> quit()
(python2.7) (23:30:09) ~$ conda install six
Fetching package metadata ...........
Solving package specifications: .

# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at /home/hyejinj/anaconda3/envs/python2.7:
#
six                       1.11.0           py27h5f960f1_1
```

I need the six package with version 1.11.0, but my python in the conda environment keeps using the default six, whose version is 1.5.2. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Do you still need an answer?

Comment: @FlyingTeller I would be good to know :)

Comment: Have you checked the result of `print(sys.path)` inside that environment?

Comment: Because I reinstalled the linux, so I can't check now. But I remember that I checked print(sys.path) but it does not solve my problem :(

Comment: I am sorry, but it will not be possible to help you if not even you can reproduce the problem. It might be that actually both versions were installed into the environment by accident, or that the PYTHONPATH contained a folder that had the older version or ....

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much though. I struggled this issue a lot, without success. Your comment still helped me to guess what was the problem.